# analogRead function not working in MATLAB

Tags: arduino-uno, matlab

I am new to Arduino and I am trying to control it through MATLAB.  I have downloaded the arduino IO package and installed it.I am using MATLAB 2014a.I have a LED and I change its brightness by changing the PWM voltage as follows :

```
a=arduino('COM3');
brightness_step = (5-0)/20;
   for i = 1:20
      writePWMVoltage(a, 11, i*brightness_step);
      val=a.analogRead(0);
      display(val)
      pause(0.1);
   end

   for i = 1:20
      writePWMVoltage(a, 11, 5-i*brightness_step);
      val=a.analogRead(0);
      display(val)
      pause(0.1);
   end
clear a
```

Everything works great except for the analogRead part which throws the following error :
**No appropriate method, property, or field analogRead for class arduino.**

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

That function is part of legacy code.

> NOTE: This solution (formerly known as "Arduino IO Package") is no
>   longer supported. It is recommended that you use Arduino support
>   packages that are developed and supported by MathWorks:
>
> - MATLAB Support Package for Arduino Hardware: Read, write, and analyze data from Arduino sensors 
>     http://www.mathworks.com/hardware-support/arduino-matlab.html
> - Simulink Support Package for Arduino Hardware: Develop algorithms that run standalone on your Arduino 
>     http://www.mathworks.com/hardware-support/arduino-simulink.html
>
> Use this legacy support only if one of the following is true:
>
> **- You are using MATLAB R2013b or earlier (but not earlier than R2011a).**

You are using 2014a, so its probably the reason `analogRead` isn't working. Get the more recent package and use this function instead:

[image: MATLAB + Arduino]

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I don't have MatLab to verify this but try this in the two places you call a.analogRead(0);

```
val=analogRead(a,0);
```

This is based on what appears to be the [classdef for the arduino object](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/32374-matlab-support-for-arduino--aka-arduinoio-package-/content/arduino.m).

Comment: Both `val=analogRead(a,0)` and `val=a.analogRead(0)` appear as valid examples in the function's description. I don't understand why one would work but not the other, but that's no reason not to try...